# error while bringup hummingbird A20 with android image

Tags: android, linux, android-activity

I have been successfully build the android image for the hummingbird and using peonixsuit uploaded the image on board, but not successful in brining the board up following is the log which i am getting in UART0 while booting the board.

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0                                                

Starting kernel ...

[    3.294581] init: width = 1024
[    3.298059] init: height = 600
[    3.301490] init: s.st_size = 2457600
[    4.112131] init: do_umount: /data 
[    4.403401] init: do_umount: /cache 
[    4.726198] init: dont need format /dev/block/UDISK
[    4.944192] init: do_umount: /databk 
[    5.624185] init: cannot find '/system/etc/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'flash_recovery'
[    6.302551] i2c i2c-1: Invalid 7-bit I2C address 0x00
[    6.596336] android_usb: already disabled
[    6.601920] init: using deprecated syntax for specifying property 'sys.usb.config', use ${name} instead
[    6.649823] init: using deprecated syntax for specifying property 'sys.usb.config', use ${name} instead
[   31.820483] start_powernow uncare mode:859320624!
[   32.517665] init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:1003  name:service.bootanim.exit
```

please help me to solve this issue.

[image: board which i am using]

Comment: This looks to me like a hardware problem. Do you have a point of reference for the A20 your'e using?

Comment: same board i have booted with dragonboard(linux) image, there was no errors